# How can I check if a button is pressed during a specific time interval in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I'm creating a game for iOS and need some help.

Simply put, random letters will be shown in a label(changing at regular interval), and the user must press the button when they recognise a pattern. If they press the button they earn points, and if they miss it, they lose points.

**For example:**

let's say they are looking for a letter repeating over one gap. They see the letters "R K W K". On the second K they would press the button. I need to be able to check if the button was pressed while that second K was displayed. I have searched here on stack overflow, but I can't really find anything specific to my situation. Thanks in advance for your responses. I'm new here, so I tried to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Make a global variable of type bool lets call it `isMatch`.

While displaying other letters make `isMatch = false;`

When you display the second 'K' (as your example) make `isMatch = true`

In you button click method check:

```
if(isMatch){
    point++;
}
else point--;
```

Make sure you change `isMatch = false` on displaying other letters.

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you are displaying `K` (say) in `UILabel` and you might be getting input in `UITextField`, what you should do is implement `ValueChanged` IBAction for `UITextField` and add all letters (K, M, X, H) etc in an array what you have on screen for now. When the text changes it will come in above IBAction, match the UITextField's text with the elements of an array. *If there is a match, you are done!*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just check in the selector for the button ... (If you're using Interface builder replace void with IBAction)

```
- (void) buttonWasPressed:(UIButton *) sender {
  if ([[[sender titleLabel] text] isEqualToString:@"K"])
      point ++;

  else 
      point --;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)yourbutton;
    {
        yourbutton.selected = ![yourbutton isSelected];
    }
```

then this

```
    [self.yourbutton isSelected];
```